# Udev does not have permissions to write to the file system

Tags: udev

I have been fighting with udev all afternoon.  Basically I have created a rule that detects when a mass storage device is plugged into the system.  This rule works and I can get it to execute a script without any issues, here it is for review purposes:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?*", SUBSYSTEM=="block", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/udevhelper.sh"
```

The problem I am running into is that the script is executed as some sort of strange user that has read-only permissions to the entire system.  The script I am executing is quite simple:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd /usr/local/bin
touch .drivedetect
echo "1" > .drivedetect
exit
```

Basically I would like udev to run this script and simply output a 1 to a file named .drivedetect within the /usr/local/bin folder.  But as I mentioned before it sees the rule and executes the rule when I plug in a drive however when it tries to run the script it comes back with *file system is read-only script quit with error code 1*.
I am currently running this on a raspberry pi zero and the latest Debian image.  udev is still being run from init.d from what I can tell because there is no systemd service for it registered.  Any help would be great and if you need any more information just ask.

Things I've tried:

```
MODE="0660"
GROUP="plugdev"
Various combinations of RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/path/to/script'" and /bin/bash
OPTIONS="last_rule"
```

And last but not least I tried running the script under the main username as well

```
#!/bin/sh
su pi drivedetect
```

Answer (score 3):

I had same issue, when I just used

```
udevadm control --reload-rules
```

after editing a udev rule.  But, if I do:

sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart

The script can edit a file.

It's not enough to reboot.  I have to do the restart after booting. It then works as expected until the next reboot.

This is on an rpi with stretch-lite.